# How to save Two Factor Auth TOTP Secret?

Tags: encryption, two-factor-authentication, totp

I'm currently developing two factor authentication based on **totp**. For this you have to generate a secret and save it on the server side and on the client-side (***usually through the QR code***).

**My Question:** How do I store it in the database? My requirements are that it's saved secure, preferably encrypted. Hashed doesn't work because I need to be able to have the plain-text value in order to calculate the **totp** secret code. When I encrypt it, with what key? Should I use a general key? Should I use the password from the user as the key? This would have the disadvantage that when a password reset is done, I can't **Decrypt** the **totp** secret key anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42795/storing-seed-for-totp?rq=1

Comment: imho you can have a master key or user specific key (indeed the passwords are not the best choice).